# getTag() returning a false string

Tags: android, string, false-positive

I've set a tag on an imageview to be "blank", so it looks like this in the xml file

```
android:tag="blank"
```

Now when I run this

```
((String) buttons[button-2].getTag() == "blank"
```

It returns false. I can't find why, any ideas? Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use:

```
((String) buttons[button-2].getTag().equals("blank")
```

For `String` comparison you must use `equals`, `==` tests references.

Comment: its used in this context : 
if (button % 4 != 0 && ((String) buttons[button].getTag().equals("blank")))
eclipse returns 'Cannot cast from boolean to String'

Comment: @Benny292, You need to parenthesize the cast.  `"blank".equals(buttons[button].getTag())` should do what you want.  As written, you are casting the result of the `equals` call to a `String`.

Comment: @Benny292 As Mike already said, you have to first get the tag and cast it to `String` and **then** compare it with "blank": `((String) buttons[button].getTag()).equals("blank"))`

Answer (score 1):

You can also `intern` the String. This always produces the same object for the same string contents, so you can do comparisons with `==`.